# Best way to store massive amounts of data

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

On my website, I currently have a giant form which now has about 700 fields. I have one column in my database for every field, and every row is a new form entry.

Over the last few years, this form has been filled out a few thousand times. This form is modified quite frequently, and the database has become very difficult to manage.

Just opening up this database in phpMyAdmin takes about a minute. I set up indexing so querying isn't slow, but this database is just not manageable.

I'm wondering what the best way to store large amounts of data, like this, would be? Is there a better practice, like using two tables and storing the users field entries in different rows?

How would you build this database structure? Would you recommend using NoSQL?

Comment: You actually need a real database design. Currently you just have one table and throw everything in it. But designing your DB is way too broad for here. Read a book or tutorial about it

Comment: Pay someone a few hundred bucks to sort this out for you

Comment: Normalize your database and put different types of facts in different tables.

Comment: Have you looked into NoSQL? [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is sort-of an open source copy of what google uses for storing large amounts of data

Comment: I don't think 700 columns is that bad
But forget about using UI to manage it

Answer (score 1):

A solution is:

Some of your columns are important and you use them in where clause and we assume their count is 10. Then your new table will have one id and 10 useful fields and another field that store other 690 datas in it as json or xml format or even commo separated values. Then you can parse that field in your program when you want show it to user.